# How to dismiss the calendar when user selects a date in ios

Tags: ios, calendar

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pmcalendar <- I am using this for my app ,my problem is
i am unable to dismiss the view automatically  once the date is selected.
Help me to fix this issue friends.This is my code,if i use    [self.pmCC dismissCalendarAnimated:NO]; means the calendar view is even not appearing.

```
- (void)calendarController:(PMCalendarController *)calendarController didChangePeriod:(PMPeriod *)newPeriod
```

{

```
if(tfTemp==tfFromDate)
{
        tfFromDate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [newPeriod.startDate dateStringWithFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]];
    [Shareinfo sharedMySingleton].tripStartDate=newPeriod.startDate;
              [self.pmCC dismissCalendarAnimated:NO];
    }

} else
{
        tfToDate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [newPeriod.endDate dateStringWithFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]];
    [Shareinfo sharedMySingleton].tripEndDate=newPeriod.endDate;

              [self.pmCC dismissCalendarAnimated:NO];
}
```

}

Comment: Don't you have a delegate on date selection in this controller ?

Comment: hi i have updated my question,Kindly check it @BharathVankireddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working Perfectly After commenting the line
    **[self calendarController:pmCC didChangePeriod:pmCC.period];**
in
    **-(void) showCalendar:(UITextField *) sender**